# Rails 4 app shows object even without calling set_object in before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4 and Scaffold to create RESTful controllers and models.

To show an object there is the show method:

```
def show
end
```

And I have a before action:

```
before_action :set_object, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

And:

```
def set_object
   @object = Object.find(params[:id])
end
```

So far, so good. But now when I removed the before action because I want to set the object within the show method. To my surprise even without calling set_object I can still access the show method and it shows me the object.

Even when removing the entire set_object method I can still oben the object in my browser.

It seems that Rails sets the object by default when passing an Id in the URL. Can somebody confirm this? What is happening?

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: @GaganGupta Textmate...why?

Comment: does it perform autosave?

Comment: I don't think so...but where do you want to get with this?

Comment: try saving it and refresh the page on the browser? :P :D

Comment: good idea... but of course :P